# Express the following formula in terms of n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, intuition

Express $$
T(2^k)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}.
$$

In terms of $n$, where $n = 2^k$.

I'm not sure how to go about with the conversion.  Can someone concisely explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$T(n)=\frac{\log_2(n)(\log_2(n)+1)}{2}$$

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but if the equation had been $
T(2^k)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2} +1.
$ would the result be what you've written +1 ?

Comment: @BobJohn: take a look at anorton's answer for more details. The answer is yes, if you add +1, then the result would be the same as what I wrote with a $+1$ as well. By saying $n=2^k$, you need to find how $k$ depends on $n$ and then plug that into every instance of $k$ in your equation.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is correct; I thought I'd work the problem in "slow motion:"

$$n=2^k$$
We have an exponential.  We want to solve for $k$, which essentially begs for a $\log$ function.  $\log_2$ is an ideal choice, as it cancels out the $2^k$ in the definition of $T$.

So, taking the $\log_2$ of both sides:
$$\log_2 n = \log_2(2^k)$$
$$\log_2 n = k\log_2(2)$$
$$\log_2 n = k$$

Substituting:
$$T(2^k) = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
$$T(2^{\log_2 n}) = \frac{\left(\log_2{n}\right)(\log_2 n+1)}{2}$$
Simplify:
$$T(n) = \frac{\left(\log_2{n}\right)(\log_2 n+1)}{2}$$